Compose Multiplatform: How to Use a mutableListOf<DataClass>
I'm trying to make a small GUI using Compose Multiplatform (primarily for desktop right now) and I'm trying to have a mutableStateListOf where the type for the List is a data class called Note. Currently I have:
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.*

data class Note(val name: String, val content: String)

@Composable
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        var notes by remember { mutableListOf<Note>() }
    }
}

Which Android Studio is giving me the error:
Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate.
It'll work if I use mutableStateOf(arrayOf(Note("1", "Note 1")) instead but I'm not sure why. I'd like to be able to start it off as an empty list and then add Notes to it later on as the user interacts with the GUI.

In your example, you use mutableListOf instead of mutableStateListOf. I think the error comes from here.

@amanin is right, also with mutableStateListOf you don't need delegation, replace var notes by with val notes =

As said in the comments, solution was to change to
val notes = mutableStateListOf<Note>()

